# javascript array push keeps repeating it self cant find out why

Tags: javascript

I cant figure out why this arrayUnd gets repeated key values. ive been on this for three weeks. I must be doing somehthing stupid. I know they are loops. but everything works except the push. it logs when the key repeats and stuff. but it somehow is adding it to it? very confusing.
Heres my Javascript

```
var array = [
              {"size":["12","22"]},
              {"color":["blue"]},
              {"design":["flower-blue"]},
                {"size":["12","22","44"]},
              {"color":["red"]},
              {"design":["flower-blue"]}
          ]
//output array
arrayUnd=[           
  {"color":["red"]}
]

//is array?
console.log(  Array.isArray(array))
function pusher(obj){
arrayUnd.push(obj)
}

function isRepeat(key,value,obj){
 // console.log(key[0])
  
  for (let item=0; item < arrayUnd.length; item++ ){
    
    if ( arrayUnd[item].hasOwnProperty(key)){
      console.log("key: " + key)
        console.log("yes")
      console.log(arrayUnd)
    }
    else{
            console.log("keyno: " + key)

        console.log("no")
        //pusher(obj)
      if ( arrayUnd[item].hasOwnProperty(key) === false){
      pusher(obj)
      }
            console.log(arrayUnd)

        }
    }
  
}
array.forEach((obj)=>{
  var a= Object.keys(obj)
    var b= Object.values(obj)
isRepeat(a,b,obj)
})

console.log(arrayUnd)
```

Comment: There should only be three  Objects in the arrayUnd

Comment: not sure what you're trying to do here, but you're passing an array as key, and an array as value.  hasOwnProperty(array of keys) will always return false, so it's just adding everything

Comment: That must be it let me try it thanks for your comment

Comment: yeah no it still ads them. i know it works cuz it tells me that the key is in or not regardless of the array key. it says yes and no if its in it. but then when i do the push it keeps looping like maybe i need a break where it doesnt loop when added

Comment: are you just trying to filter out duplicate keys for single key:value objects?

Comment: no im checking so i dont add the duplicates to the arrayUnd

Comment: so if inside the result arrayUnd an object already contains a key that a new object contains, ignore them?  and the objects are always one key,value pair?

Comment: yes i only want three of them becuase other keys are repeated, eventualy i will loop through the values and bind them to the key. that way its should be a small array of three keys.

Comment: correction: toString of a single element array works fine, since ["some"].toString actually just returns "some"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is checking all objects to see if they don't match.  At least one of them won't match, so it will try to push that many times.  You need to check all elements, and after checking them all for existence decide if you want to push or not.
Current logic is equivalent to: if anything in arrUnd doesn't match, push me each time I check.
`some` works here, because it checks if anything matches, and returns true or false, which you can then use to decide if you want to push or not (only once, after I've found if anything in the array matches, deciding using the final result).

Using [some](https://www.google.com/search?q=mdn%20array.prototype.some&oq=mdn%20array.prototype.some&aqs=chrome..69i57.3319j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) to check if any other element with same key exists.  Push if nothing found.

```js
var array = [{
    "size": ["12", "22"]
  },
  {
    "color": ["blue"]
  },
  {
    "design": ["flower-blue"]
  },
  {
    "size": ["12", "22", "44"]
  },
  {
    "color": ["red"]
  },
  {
    "design": ["flower-blue"]
  }
]
//output array
arrayUnd = [{
  "color": ["red"]
}]

//is array?
console.log(Array.isArray(array))

function pusher(obj) {
  arrayUnd.push(obj)
}

function isRepeat(key, value, obj) {
  if(!arrayUnd.some(x => x.hasOwnProperty(key[0])))
    arrayUnd.push(obj)
}
array.forEach((obj) => {
  var a = Object.keys(obj)
  var b = Object.values(obj)
  isRepeat(a, b, obj)
})

console.log(arrayUnd)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing an array to `isRepeat` instead of the key and value of the object.

`Object.keys()` returns an array, even if the object only has one key.

When you check `if ( arrayUnd[item].hasOwnProperty(key) === false)`, `arrayUnd[item].hasOwnProperty(key)` will always be false, so the object will always get pushed to your array.

You can fix this by accessing the first key and value of each object:

```js
array.forEach((obj)=>{
  var a= Object.keys(obj)
    var b= Object.values(obj)
isRepeat(a[0],b[0],obj)
})
```

Comment: will try i did that with the key[0]. but lets see if that works

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code keeps pushing object to arrayUnd it's because when it iterates through the array it checks for the array key if its present if not it pushes it to arrayUnd, now you have 2 problems first you are not actually checking for the array key to match you comparing object so you will always get false , and second is that each time you push to the array the length of your array grow and so the number of iterations increases

you can achieve this in two lines of code

```js
var array = [
  {"size":["12","22"]},
  {"color":["blue"]},
  {"design":["flower-blue"]},
  {"size":["12","22","44"]},
  {"color":["red"]},
  {"design":["flower-blue"]}
]
//output array
arrayUnd=[           
{"color":["red"]}
]

array.forEach(p=>Object.entries(p).forEach(p=>{
  !arrayUnd.some(o=>o.hasOwnProperty(p[0])) ? arrayUnd.push({[p[0]]:p[1]}):null
}))
console.log(arrayUnd)
```

Comment: right so how do i prevent re iteration after added.

Comment: the problem is that my keys wont be defined later they are going to be random. so it has to check for new added keys which might not be in any array

Comment: I can provide a more elegant solution to that if you want

Comment: sure everything can help. its complicated because going through loops confuse me. the answer above works but if you have something better ill take it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var inpAry = [
    { "size": ["12", "22"] },
    { "color": ["blue"] },
    { "design": ["flower-blue"] },
    { "size": ["12", "22", "44"] },
    { "color": ["red"] },
    { "design": ["flower-blue"] }
];

var opAry = [
    { "color": ["red"] }
];

inpAry.forEach(inpAryElem => {
    var ipAryElemKeys = Object.keys(inpAryElem);
    var ipAryElemVals = Object.values(inpAryElem);
    ipAryElemKeys.forEach((ipAryElmKey,ipAryElemKyIdx) => {
        var isKeyPresent = false;
        opAry.forEach(opAryElem => {
            if(opAryElem[ipAryElmKey]) {
                isKeyPresent = true;
                opAryElem[ipAryElmKey].push(...ipAryElemVals[ipAryElemKyIdx]);
            }
        });
        if(!isKeyPresent) {
            opAry.push({[ipAryElmKey]:ipAryElemVals[ipAryElemKyIdx]});
        }
    })
});

console.log(opAry);
```